# Reloading entities as though they just got output from a query

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lazy-loading

I would like to refresh managed entities, I used Session.refresh but it's been causing StackOverflowError because I mapped bi-directionnal relationships.

Plus, I don't want one-to-many relationships to be reloaded nor to keep the same state, I want them to be non-initialized as though their parents entities were a query result.

I tried this :

```
@Override
public void refresh(IdentifiableByIdImpl entity) {
    Query  query;
    Object refreshedEntity;
    try {
        query = session.createQuery(
                "FROM " + entity.getClass().getSimpleName() +
                   "WHERE id = " + entity.getId()
        );

        refreshedEntity = query.uniqueResult();
        copyProperties(refreshedEntity, entity);
    } catch(StackOverflowError e) {
        System.err.println("S.O");
    }
}
```

But it keeps triggering a StackOverflowError.

A simple way would be to return the "refreshedEntity" nonetheless I find this way non-flexible.